# I want create a button that adds a new form

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

First I show one form and I want that my user have the possibility to add a new form in the same page. So I want to create a button that adds a new form.

```
[contact-form-7 id="2" title="Form"] <!-- #Form shortcode-->
         <input type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add form" />  <!-- #Form shortcode-->

<script>
    function add_fields() {
       var d = document.getElementById("content");

       d.innerHTML += "[contact-form-7 id='2' title="Form"]";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your short code is read by wordpress to create the HTML form (server side).

Your javavscript action is client side, so wordpress can't read it to create the form.

One solution may be to create the forms, and hide it by default. But you're user won't be able to create as much form as he wants.
Or maybe load the form in ajax (don't know wordpress, not sure about that), but it's a bit harder.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="/wp-includes/js/addInput.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form method="POST">

     <div id="dynamicInput">

          Entry 1<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">

     </div>

     <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">

</form>

<script>


    var counter = 1;

var limit = 3;

function addInput(divName){

     if (counter == limit)  {

          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");

     }

     else {

          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

          newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";

          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);

          counter++;

     }

}
</script>
```